# Applicability of Ritz method,weak formulation

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, operator-theory

Im trying to find values of c, when I can use Ritz method for this differential equation.$ L_cu=-u^{\prime \prime}+c u=f(x) ; \quad u^{\prime}(0)=0 ; \quad u(1)=b $ for $ u \in C^{2}([0 ; 1]) $ (this is differential formulation).Here is my try:
at first I show that $(L_cu,v)-(u,L_cv)=b(u(1)-v(1))$ and I find out that if b!=0 then my operator L is not self adjoint,is that true? Then I try to show that $L_c$ is positive finding out minimal
eigenvalue ,$L_cu=\lambda u$,then i find that c must be greater then $-\pi^2/4$,but my teacher says that Im working out only for strong solutions,what should I do to find out applicability of Ritz method when working on weak solutions? Any hints or ideas or links to books or lectures would be appreciated.